# How to validate a user selection of multiple checkboxes using a button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm learning VB.net language and I'm creating a simple app, which the user can select up to 5 numbers using checkboxes, and the button on windows form app will check if the user has marked up to 5 numbers. Otherwise, a dialog message will appear returning that user can only check up to 5 numbers, and the exceded choice is unchecked, keeping the 5 options checked.
On some tests, I could do that setting the CheckBox1.CheckBoxChanged with the following code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged, CheckBox5.CheckedChanged, CheckBox6.CheckedChanged

    Dim check As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, Object)
    If check.Checked Then
        counter += 1
    Else
        counter -= 1
    End If
    If counter > 5 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You can only pick up to 5 numbers!")
        check.Checked = False
    End If

End Sub
```

On this way the program has worked perfectly. But when I put the code above inside the Button1_Click, it doesn't work. The message box dialog appears and keeps looping until all checkboxes are unchecked. The code I wrote inside the Button1_Click it follows above:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each check As CheckBox In Me.grpMega.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If check.Checked Then
            counter += 1
        Else
            counter -= 1
        End If
        If counter > 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You can only pick up to 5 numbers!")
            check.Checked = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I've beend making some searches over the internet to find up a solution, but with no success. If anybody could help me, I'll be so grateful. Thanks so much for your attention. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: _But it's failed_  could you edit you question (not add a comment) with a clear explanation of what it failing means?  Have you debugged the Button Click event and stepped through it?  Suspect (if this is all in same form) that first thing in that event would be to set the value of counter to 0, then only increment if  check.checked

Comment: Probably easier to not subtract.  Just set the counter to zero and add for every checked box.

Comment: @Hursey Sorry for my mistake on about it's failed. I meant that when click on button with the code above, if I select six checkboxes, the message returns only after two clicks, and the message keeps on a loop, until all checkboxes are unchecked. When I use the first code above (the code written inside CheckBox1.CheckedChanged), it works perfectly. If I select six options, the message box returns and unchecks the last option.

Comment: @LarsTech And how can I do that, to add for every checked box?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted that would untick checkboxes.  perhaps before expecting anyone to try answer, as per first comment, edit your question with a clear and concise explanation of the problem and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: In the Button click handler, your code is `dim checkedCount = grpMega.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).Count(Function(c) c.Checked)`, nothing else -- Since you're learning, set `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` to `ON` right away, in the related properties of Visual Studio (`Tools->Options->Project and Solutions-> VB Defaults`). Don't look back. You cannot have something like this:  `Dim check As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, Object)` (3 bad mistakes in one line). Those options set to ON will help you write better code

Comment: @Jimi Thanks a lot, Jimi. I'll follow your instructions and testing the code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jimi Your answer has worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!